# Is it possible to install iOS apps in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: simulator

I want to understand if is there any way we can install or download the apps on the iOS simulator without Xcode.
I know we cannot install Appstore on the simulator, so is there any possible way we can trick the simulator to install the app?